# How can I get a netwire network to simulate execution over a discrete set of instants?

Tags: haskell, frp

I have been looking at using netwire, but cannot see how I can pump instants through a series of wires that do not depend upon actual time.  That is, is there some way to take a wire of type `Wire e m a b`, and a variable of type `[(Time, a)]`, and get back something of type `[b]`?  Everything in the examples seems to be geared towards having a real time clock generate instants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into the `Control.Wire.Session` module.  There you will find the utilities to construct your own clock.  In particular you will want to look into the `Session` data type and the `genSession` helper function.  This is about the clock.  The second issue is inputs:  What input is passed to one instant is decided by the author of the main loop.

In fact if you have just a list of times coupled with inputs, I recommend calculating the time deltas and then using `stepWire` directly (instead of `stepSession`), bypassing the whole session machinery.  The only constraint is that time is always of type `Double`.  Example:

```
loop :: [(Time, a)] -> Time -> Wire e m a b -> m [Either e b]
loop [] _ _ = return []
loop ((t, x):ins) t' w' = do
    (mx, w) <- stepWire w' (t - t') x
    fmap (mx:) (loop ins t w)
```

Untested code, but should work.  The second argument is the starting time.

Comment: that's doesn't seem to compile as is, but I think I can get there from here, thanks.